# Elixir Arc: Extend S3 Header Expiry Time

Tags: amazon-s3, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm using the arc attachment library for elixir: https://github.com/stavro/arc, and I'm wanting to increase the expiry time of the signed generated URL's.

The default expiry time for S3 headers is set here:
https://github.com/stavro/arc/blob/3d1754b3e65e0f43b87c38c8ba696eadaeeeae27/lib/arc/storage/s3.ex#L3

Which produces the following in the link request to S3:
...&X-Amz-Date=20180125T203430Z&**X-Amz-Expires=300**&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=...

The [readme](https://github.com/stavro/arc#s3-object-headers) says that you can extend the S3 header expires by adding a `s3_object_headers` method to your uploader:

Presuming that this is what I needed to do, here's what I added:

  `def s3_object_headers(version, {file, scope}) do
    [expires: 600]
  end`

But I still get the same Amz-Expires value (300). I also tried using :expires_in and :expires_at as the code seemed to reference those values, but got the same result.

What have I done wrong or failed to understand about how this works?

Comment: I believe you need to pass `expires_in: 600` to the options passed to `YourModule.url/3` function. At least that's what I figured out reading the code and README you've linked to. Can you see if that works?

Comment: Dogbert, thats what it was - you were right. I'll just have to refactor my URL functions to include that parameter. If you want to create an answer I'll accept it as correct. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`expires_in` needs to be passed in the last argument to your module's `url/3` function, not put in `s3_object_headers/2`:

```
YourModule.url(..., ..., expires_in: 600)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the readme might be wrong by reading the [signing](https://github.com/stavro/arc/blob/3d1754b3e65e0f43b87c38c8ba696eadaeeeae27/lib/arc/storage/s3.ex#L74) and it's 
`:expires_in` (or `:expire_in`) that you need to define in `s3_object_headers`

Comment: Thanks Micael. I tried both `:expires_in` and `:expire_in`, but the same result.

Comment: Perhaps someone who has used arch can chime in